# JQuery working Intermittently

Tags: jquery, html, liquid

I'm hoping I'm missing an obvious solution here. The below code only works intermittently. If you load with a cleared cache / incognito mode, then click on .gifslide twice before the page has finished loading - it breaks. Typing that I realize how specific this is but regardless, please help.

The offending code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gifslide").on('click', function () {
      $('.gifslide').toggle(); 
 // below is a workaround to make 
 // it appear the the image is sliding upward and not down.   
      $("#load-gif-container").slideToggle(500);
      $('.gif-content').slideToggle(500);  
    });
  });
```

It's HTML sidekick:

```
  <div id="load-gif-container">
    <img src="{{'source.png' | asset_url}}" id="load-gif"  />
  </div>
  <div class="gifslide"><span>&#9650<br>Expand</span>
  </div>
  <div class="gif-content">
    <img src="{{ 'source.gif' | asset_url }}", id="gif-banner"/>
  </div>
```

ya I'm programming in liquid but aside from that - what's the problem here?

UPDATE / EDIT:

When I said "it breaks" I should have said ".gif-content displays without performing the slideToggle. #load-gif container also doesn't toggle but .gifslide does". No errors displayed. It does look ridiculous but nothing in the console that would help.

I replied back to current comment on this question explaining what happened when I tried that.

I've also tried not triggering the function until the image inside of #gif-content loads. It didn't work but I have a feeling that this is where the problem is stemming from. It's a massive gif, above the fold, surrounded by other massive images. I'm not sure there is enough compressing / minimizing in the world to get all of these things to function smoothly on limited connections but I'm hoping that I'm wrong.

Comment: try `$(document).on('.gifslide', 'click', function() {`

Comment: no error or so? "it breaks"? what was broken? please be specific.

Comment: well, you're making changes to the images before they've finished loading, why not just bind the click handler on load?

Answer (score 0):

You have the click event binding **after** the document is ready. When reloading the page under normal circumstances, your script is cached and can therefore give you the functionality you are looking for. The reason you are running into this problem only in incognito mode or after you have cleared cache is because your script is not cached, and therefore not accessible. Your script is still loading, the page is not "ready", and so it is not able to pick up your clicks/doubleclicks ... while it is still loading.

There are a few other changes I would recommend as well that will give you better performance (obviously after the document is ready) and more consistent behavior:

```
// from
$(document).ready(function() {});

// to
$(function() {});

// these are equivalent and the latter is more terse
```

If you are ever in a situation where there is more than one .gifslide in a document, clicking on one of them will propagate that click event to all of them. Additionally, to clear the event queue of any other click events related to .gifslide, use .off() before .on(). You can resolve these issues like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.gifslide').off('click').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(event.target).toggle();
    });
});
```

It is also recommended to cache your elements in a variable. In terms of performance, touching the DOM is very expensive. So...

```
$(function() {
    var $gifSlide = $('.gifslide'),
        $loadGif = $('#load-gif-container'),
        $gifContent = $('.gif-content');

    $gifSlide.off('click').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(event.target).toggle();

        $loadGif.slideToggle(500);
        $gifContent.slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Finally, because you have a span nested within .gifslide, if someone clicks on the span, you may end up handling the click event behavior on that target instead of the .gifslide (what you want).

```
$(function() {
    var $gifSlide = $('.gifslide'),
        $loadGif = $('#load-gif-container'),
        $gifContent = $('.gif-content');

    $gifSlide.off('click').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $me = ($(event.target).is('.gifslide')) ? $(event.target): $(event.target).closest('.gifslide');
        $me.toggle();

        $loadGif.slideToggle(500);
        $gifContent.slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow - thank you so much, this is incredibly thorough! Unfortunately, it's still not working. When I tried implementing your solution - upon clicking on .gifslide (under the same conditions I described above) the span disappears correctly but the gif is no where to be seen.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry it's not exactly what solved your issue. If the span is disappearing as well as the gif, the "var $me" part could be catching the wrong event target. Possibly replacing the $me.toggle() with your original $('.gifslide').toggle() might solve it?